# Removing the last slash from query parameter using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the last slash character from query parameter's value using `.htaccess`.

Suppose I have the following URL:

```
www.example.com/?key_=/job_category/mobile/
```

Then from `/job_category/mobile/` I want to remove the last slash.

After removing the last slash, it would redirect to `www.example.com/snapshots/job_category/mobile.html,` but with my current settings it redirects to `www.example.com/snapshots/job_category/mobile/.html`.

My current `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snapshots/%1.html [R=301,QSD]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to capture anything in `RewriteRule`, as all necessary information is already captured by `RewriteCond`. To remove the trailing slash use an expression like `\/*$` (zero or more slashes at the end):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key_=(.*?)\/*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /snapshot%1.html [R=301,QSD]
```